# Adding new customer from backend not inserting store id

Tags: admin, customer

I am using magento 1.7.0.2.
I am having issue regarding store id.
When I add new customer from front end by sign up it adds store id in "Customer Entity" table.
But When I try to add customer from backend manually it doesn't insserts 'store id' in "Customer Entity" table.It inserss '0' when adding with admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple.
go to /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
and just before //send welcome email part

```
// Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save', array(
//                    'customer'  => $customer,
//                    'request'   => $this->getRequest()
//                ));
```

And put following code there.

```
$storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
$customer->save();
```

That's it now you can choose store from backend and will also be inserted in to customer_entity table.

solution find from [phprocks](http://phprocks.letsnurture.com/)

Comment: Thanks its working properly.no need to hardcode.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for admin created users Magento gets store id dynamically and uses websites default store. You can only set website to which a customer belongs.

Answer (score 1):

The store ID just shows where the account was created. There's no way in the backend to change that value, from what I saw. You can, of course, change the value in the database, and it will reflect the change under the customer's "Personal Information" > "Account Created in:" in the backend view.

You can change the customer's store programmatically like so (not tested):

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($customer_email);
$customer->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
$customer->save();
```

Comment: Isn't its possible to set new field in backend add customer form to select store and insert store id in "Customer Entity" table in DB.

Comment: @Nilesh That is definitely possible with a small Magento extension. [This article](http://codemagento.blogspot.com/2012/05/add-new-custom-field-to-customer.html) may be of some help.

Comment: Yes it works but it is for front end sign up form not for backend admin add customer form

Answer (score 0):

For a Magento 1.4.1.1, I have done an overload module in order to modify the behaviour of this controller.
But if in the file app/code/local/Aetaebc/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
In     public function saveAction() I put:

```
// Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save', array(
//                    'customer'  => $customer,
//                    'request'   => $this->getRequest()
//                ));
```

and

```
$storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
$customer->save();
```

as proposed by phprocks
The store_id is good but it's impossible to send an email with a new password to the customer via the Magento backoffice.

So, for my usage, I decided to just force the $tore _Id value.

```
.../...
            Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_customer_prepare_save',
                array('customer' => $customer, 'request' => $this->getRequest())
            );

            $storeId = 4; // force StoreId 
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId); 

            $customer->save();
.../...
```

It's not ideal but it works .